# apply a custom made graphic to a stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've created an arch using pen tool. Now I want to apply custom graphics to the arch. How do I achieve that?

[image]

^ here's what I drew.

And I want to apply custom graphics to that shape. For example, a custom graphics like this:  (pls disregard the white bar) 
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better what your desired effect is, possibly with a screenshot? I'm having a hard time imagining what it is that you want to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw an arc:

   [image]
2. Drag and drop your image to the brushes palette. As options for new brush dialog choose art brush.
3. Select path and apply art brush.

   [image]

**Notes**: Your original imagery is of pretty bad quality. If you were to use vector images or higher res images instead you would have better quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried what you suggested.  Instead of the graphic fitting just the stroke/line, it covers extra areas and it all looks weird now. How do i have the graphic cover only the stroke?